# Searching a tree recursively

Tags: recursion, tree, julia

This code is trying to build a simple tree structure, then search it for matches. Some of it's working OK.

```
mutable struct Tree
    node::String
    children::Vector
end

Tree(str::String) =  Tree(str, [])
Tree(a::Vector) = Tree("root", a)

function Base.show(io::IO, tree::Tree, level = 0)
    print(io, "\t" ^ level * tree.node * "\n")
    for child in tree.children
        show(io, child, level + 1)
    end
end

function Base.length(t::Tree, counter = 1)
    for child in t.children
        if child != nothing
            counter += 1
            counter = length(child, counter)
        end
    end
    return counter
end

function buildtree(path)
    root = Tree(splitpath(path)[end])
    if isdir(path)
        for f in readdir(path)
            push!(root.children, buildtree(joinpath(path, f)))
        end
    end
    return root
end

function findfirstitem(t::Union{Tree, Array}, key)
    result = missing
    # if a number, return some of the children
    if isa(key, Int) || isa(key, UnitRange)
        return t.children[key]
    end
    # or look for a matching node/key
    if isa(key, String)
        for child in t.children
            if occursin(key, child.node)
                return child.node
            end
            if isa(child, Union{Tree, Array})
                findfirstitem(Tree(child.node, child.children), key)
            end
        end
    end
    return result
end

filetree = buildtree(homedir() * "/.julia/registries/General/A")
```

The top level queries work OK;

```
julia> findfirstitem(filetree, "A")

"ACME"

julia> findfirstitem(filetree, 2:4)

3-element Array{Any,1}:
ADCME
Compat.toml
Deps.toml
Package.toml
Versions.toml
---------------------------

AIBECS
Compat.toml
Deps.toml
Package.toml
Versions.toml
---------------------------

AIControl
Compat.toml
Deps.toml
Package.toml
Versions.toml
---------------------------

julia> findfirstitem(filetree, "ACME")

"ACME"
```

But the recursion isn't unwinding like I think it might:

```
julia> findfirstitem(filetree, "Compat")

missing
```

and my head is starting to hurt with this recursion...

Comment: Seems to me that `findfirstitem(Tree(child.node, child.children), key)` will fail if `child` is an `Array`? BTW why not use dispatch for that part?

Comment: I was trying to make the `children` field be a `::Tree` as well, but these recursive type definitions are hard, hence the `Union`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function shouldn't be tasked to look into `children` as this is taken care of by the recursion...

```
function findfirstitem(t::Union{Tree, Array}, key)
    # if a number, return some of the children
    if key isa Int || key isa UnitRange
        return t.children[key]
    end
    # or look for a matching node/key
    if key isa String
        if occursin(key,t.node)
            return t
        else
            for child in t.children
                found = findfirstitem(child, key)
                if !ismissing(found)
                    return found
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return missing
end
```

But it depends on your expectations of the search algorithm. Should it search into depth or breadth first?